# Select closest value in sqlite not working

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this table with the following records:

```
id(int/11)   date(varchar/255)

0            2014-10-14 01:32:07 +0000
1            2014-11-09 12:45:09 +0000
2            2014-12-23 08:21:10 +0000
3            2014-12-24 05:19:55 +0000
```

All I'm trying to do is get the value closer to a certain date I am sending to analyze the sql below is the syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM records ORDER BY ABS('2014-10-14 01:20:55 +0000' - value) WHERE status = '1' LIMIT 1
```

in this case the syntax would return me the **ID 0**, but I receive the following error:

```
near "00": syntax error
```

What's the problem with my syntax?

Comment: There's no `value` or `status` columns in the table you show.

Comment: Please note that subtraction works only with numbers, so you end up subtracting `2014` from `2014`, which is always zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have reordered the `ORDER BY` and the `WHERE` clause: `ORDER BY` needs to be after `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM records
WHERE status = '1'
ORDER BY ABS('2014-10-14 01:20:55 +0000' - value)
LIMIT 1
```